# lambda's method? Mats' example code confuse me .

Tags: ruby, methods, lambda

```
def memoize
  cache = {}
  lambda { |*args| 
    unless cache.has_key?(args)
      cache[args] = self[*args]
    end
    cache [args]
  }
end

factorial =  lambda {|x| return 1 if x== 0; x*factorial[x-1];}.memoize

puts factorial.call 10
```

The code is from  book "The ruby programming language ". 
But it confuse me : how can the method(memoize) apply to a lambda as its method?
Can lambda followed by other lambda with dot(.) as its own method?

```
lambda {|x| return 1 if x== 0; x*factorial[x-1];}.memoize
```

BTW: The above code  works  in irb, but ruby interpreter encounter error as following:

```
memoize.rb:11: private method `memoize' called for #<Proc:0x0000000103bba018@memoize.rb:11> (NoMethodError)
```

Why?

Answer (score 7):

Where you're saying this:

```
def memoize
  #...
end
```

I think you mean to say this:

```
class Proc
  def memoize
    #...
  end
end
```

That would add a public `memoize` method to Procs and `lambda { ... }` (or `-> { ... }` in newer Rubies) gives you a Proc instance.

Now on to `memoize` itself. Methods return the value of their last expression and for `memoize`, that last expression is this:

```
lambda { |*args| 
  unless cache.has_key?(args)
    cache[args] = self[*args]
  end
  cache [args]
}
```

So `memoize` returns a wrapper for the Proc (`self`) that is a closure over `cache` and all this wrapper does is:

1. Check to see if `cache` has an entry for the argument list in question (the Array `args`) .
2. If we don't have a cached value then compute the original Proc's value (`self[*args]`) and store it in the cache.
3. Return the cached value.

You can use the [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D) method to execute a Proc so `proc.call(a, b)` is the same as `proc[a, b]`.

Answer (score 4):

The object at the top level is [main](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/), any method defined there is added as a private instance method to `Object` (so they're available everywhere).

Why does it work inside a irb session? because of the [context mode](http://tagaholic.me/2009/05/29/exploring-how-to-configure-irb.html#context_mode) (also [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/IRB/WorkSpace/new/class)), which is *3* by default in irb. Use for example value *0* (`irb --context-mode 0`), and now they will be added as private methods as usual.

It would probably be preferable for pedagogical purposes if the snippet explicitly defined which class was being modified instead of using the implicit top level.

Comment: *Private* instance method of Object, no? Hence the specific error message (which I also see in irb).

Comment: @mu: yeah, as private, added to the answer. The thing is, at least with irb 1.9.3p125, it adds it as public.